# Pocketsphinx Build small vocabulary model

Tags: model, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I want to build a small vocabulary model in german for pocketsphinx (.lm) which can only recognize the german numbers from 0-9. Using the Voxforge de-de model the performance was VERY bad (nearly no recognition). I tried TIDIGTS with a similar approach in english- which uses a specialized model only containing numbers. This one works properly. So I obviously need to build a .lm Model only containing my numbers- for that purpose I already recorded lots of wav files and transcribed them in the required XML-format. But when I look at https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutoriallm/ how to do it I only get hints how to build a language model with large vocabularies or how to build on using SRILM- which is totally useless for me, because of the restrictive license. So how do I build a LM from my wav data?

Comment: Hello Nikolay, unfortunately I can't use vosk in my setup, for reasons I can't disclose out of company security reasons, but thanks for the tip anyway. My VR is working quite flawlessly now.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is what I did: I used a generic german model (the one from voxforge.com), converted the .lm.bin to a .lm file with sphinx_lm_convert, and then edited out everything but the numbers I needed. I then used my recorded audio material to adapt the model with sphinxtrain (using sphinx_fe, bw, map-adapt). It now is relatively reliable (about 80% recognition). I additionally implemented a false positive rejection by modifying the grammar and the dictionary with a reject word (FALSE in my case) and this is also up to 70%.

Comment: Improved the recognition Rate to about 90% by using additional recordings. The Trick is to use many recordings of the same word by each speaker, you'll need about 40 people to bring it up to a fairly high recognition rate. False positive rejection can be imrpoved by naming FALSE-clauses for every phoneme in the .lm (it's 80% in my case now)